# Can't play currently recorded mp4 videos on my android phone

Tags: video, media-player, mp4

I have a gopro camera which records MP4 videos. My android phone was always capable of playing these files; but recently I have recorded two videos and my phone just says I do not support this type of file for playing! What's wrong? What may be happened to my phone or camera or recorded files?

Comment: @M4T I have tried to play files in S5 with its default video player

Comment: well, check this files Screen size and can you try it with Powerfull video player like `Mx player`?

Answer (score 0):

Try play it with [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc&hl=en)  media player for android. It can play mp4.